# What could cause a specific area of an Android layout to stop responding to button clicks?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

A user reports that a specific area of the layout of our app stops responding to taps (button click is not fired).

We have several keypad layouts that get swapped in and out. Here's how we do it:

```
keypad1.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.GONE);
keypad2.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.VISIBLE);
keypad2.measure(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
int newDimension = (int) (keypad2.getMeasuredHeight() + getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.keypad_toggle_button_height));

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) keypadContainer.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.height = newDimension;
keypadContainer.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

The parent layout has `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` so this layout change is smoothly animated.

The user can access **all** the buttons on `keypad1`. When `keypad2` is loaded into the view, the user is able to tap **most** of the buttons, except for the buttons on the **bottom part of the layout**. Because `keypad2` is **slightly taller** than `keypad1`, I am inclined to think that maybe this problem occurs because the layout hasn't updated properly after being resized, and is not receiving the touch events.

Needless to say this works perfectly for us and the bulk of our users, and we have not been able to reproduce the issue on any emulator or device in our possession. The affected system is a Samsung Galaxy S5, running Lollipop (Android 22). We have received screenshots of the app from the user and it looks identical to what we would expect from that screen size and resolution.

What are we doing wrong? How can we troubleshoot it?

Thanks!!!

**EDIT**: here is the relevant layout XML fragment.

```
            <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/keypad_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/keypad_toggle_button_height"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/toggle_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/keypad_toggle_button_height"
                android:background="@drawable/toggle"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="toggleKeyboard"
                />

            <com.app.views.KeyboardViewA
                android:id="@+id/keypad_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent">
            </com.app.views.KeyboardViewA>

            <com.app.views.KeyboardViewB
                android:id="@+id/keypad_2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:visibility="gone">
            </com.app.views.KeyboardViewB>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: are these keypads wrapped into some other layouts? You are hiding the actual keypad but the wrapping layout might be still on top of the new one.

Comment: Thanks @mihail, I've added the XML layout to the question above. The keypads are all sibling views in the same parent container.

Comment: could be one layout is on top of another, could you try using giving layout width and height to avoid overlap?

Comment: only assumptions, but this looks strange - one view has transparent background, the other has visibility=gone. Other thing I don't really like is that you have all possible keypads into that view. I'd prefer to have only one keypad container layout and just add/remove the keypad controls to/from it instead of hiding and showing them.

Answer (score 1):

Without being able to reproduce the problem, I can't be sure that any of the following will help, but here are my suggestions:

*Change how `measure()` is called:* You are calling `measure()` like this:

```
keypad2.measure(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

This translates to `keypad2.measure(-1, -2)` when `measure()` is defined as (from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#measure(int,%20int))):

**measure**

> void measure (int widthMeasureSpec, 
>                   int heightMeasureSpec)
>
> This is called to find out how big a view should be. The parent supplies constraint information in the width and height parameters.

So, your setup and call to `measure()` should look something like this:

```
int layoutWidth = ((LinearLayout) (keypad2.getParent())).getWidth();
int widthMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(layoutWidth, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
int heightMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
keypad2.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
```

I am not sure exactly what happens with the way you have it but, since it works most of the time, it might be OK or it might be something that haunts you in only some situations.

One other thing that occurred to me that you might want to try and that is to call `forceLayout()` on the key pad you are about to display to make sure it gets laid out properly.

Comment: Thank you for these directions. We have deployed a new version and are hoping to be able to confirm that it's resolved the situation. As the bounty time is running out and this appears to be the only substantial suggestion, I'll send those points over to you. I'll post an update as soon as I know if it works or not.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not fix the problem. Thanks for trying anyway!